# R - gsub paste combination returns gibberish

Tags: r, text, paste, gsub

I am performing text analysis and trying to do some cleaning.

I need to remove the following terms (if they occur) from a single element vector in R.  The sample text and replacement I developed works well:

```
library(stringr)

original.v <- c("Every dog has its day")
remove.v <- c("Every", "has", "day")

gsub(x = original.v, pattern = paste(remove.v, collapse = "|"), replacement = "")

[1] " dog  its "
```

However when I attempt to apply this to my data (The actual text is much longer. However this sample yields the same result):

```
D2020 <- c("BIDEN: . . . he knows what the outcome will be. BIDEN: . . . If you knew anything about. . . BIDEN: . . . we’re going to be in a position where we can create hard, hard, good jobs by making sure the")
```

with:

```
library(stringr)

remove <- c("WALLACE:", "BIDEN:", "TRUMP:", "[crosstalk]", "[crosstalk]-", 
            "[to Biden]", "[laughing]", "[unintelligible]", "WELKER:")

gsub(D2020, pattern = paste(remove, collapse = "|"), replacement = "")
```

I get:

```
"...wwmw....Ifywy......w’pww,,jym"
```

Instead of:

```
. . . he knows what the outcome will be. BIDEN: . . . If you knew anything about. . . . . . we’re going to be in a position where we can create hard, hard, good jobs by making sure the")
```

I've attempted to research this on the Internet. However nobody has encountered this error.

Note that my original loading syntax was as follows:

```
sample <- read.table("C:/Users/jesse/Desktop/Election/Sample.txt", header=FALSE, 
                     encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: You need to escape your `remove` items first, see [`regex.escape` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60966689/3832970) here. E.g., `[to Biden]` matches `t`, `o`, space, `B`, `i`, `d`, `e` and `n`, not `[to Biden]` string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Does this apply to the text I am attempting to run the function on too?

Comment: It applies to any literal text you want to use  as part of a regex pattern. Escape it first.